# Python: Least Squares Support Vector Machine (LS-SVM)

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, least-squares, reference-implementation

I'm looking for a Python package for a LS-SVM or a way to tune a normal SVM from scikit-learn to a Least-Squares Support Vector Machine for a classification problem.

The goal of a SVM is to maximize the margin while softly penalizing points that lie on the wrong side of the margin boundary. The function that is used is a Quadratic Programming (OP) problem.

A LS-SVM which defines a least squares cost function and replaces the inequality contraints with equality constraints and is a Linear Programming (LP) problem.

[Wikipedia: LS-VSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares_support_vector_machine)

Does someone ever tried something like that and can help me?

Comment: I've implemented a version using numpy an scipy, it can be found on this jupyter notebook in one of my Github repos: https://github.com/RomuloDrumond/LSSVM/blob/master/LSSVM.ipynb

Comment: I am adding an answer as I do not have the reputation to comment. @Hans, I am wondering whether you ever managed to find an implementation of an LS-SVM regressor in Python? It does not appear that FukuML has what you (and I) are looking for.

Comment: but how to call this algorithms?

Comment: @phappy, Could you please review my answer? If something missing let me know. Else, could you please mark it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [FukuML](https://pypi.org/project/FukuML/).

In their description (Version 0.4.1) they write:

- Support Vector Machine

  - Primal Hard Margin Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Dual Hard Margin Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Polynomial Kernel Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Gaussian Kernel Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Soft Polynomial Kernel Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Soft Gaussian Kernel Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Polynomial Kernel Support Vector Machine Multi Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Gaussian Kernel Support Vector Machine Multi Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Soft Polynomial Kernel Support Vector Machine Multi Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Soft Gaussian Kernel Support Vector Machine Multi Classification Learning Algorithm
  - Probabilistic Support Vector Machine Learning Algorithm
  - **Least Squares Support Vector Machine Binary Classification Learning Algorithm**
  - **Least Squares Support Vector Machine Multi Classification Learning Algorithm**
  - Support Vector Regression Learning Algorithm

As you can see, they have the feature you're after.

[image]

Comment: But does it have a least squares support vector machine **regression** algorithm?

Comment: Yes, it does. Look at the last item in the list.